# CSS Animate issue

Tags: html, css, zooming, css-animations

Ever since I added "position absoulte" to my div ".container" in my code below, my CSS animate code zooms in from the bottom then hiccups and positions itself to the center.

How can I make my animate zoom just zoom in right to the center without this hiccup where it goes down first then a second later it automatically moves to the center?

If I remove the position absolute from the .container div the animate zoom works just fine but it's not centered anymore vertically (just horizontally). The reason I used position absolute and left 0 and right 0 was to center it both ways.

Here is my code:

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  font-family: 'Lato', serif;
  background: linear-gradient(white 70px, #007580 70px);
  -webkit-text-size-adjust: none;
}

header,
footer {
  background: #007580
}

body,
main {
  display: flex;
  flex: 1;
}

body {
  flex-flow: column;
}

header {
  min-height: 35px;
}

footer {
  min-height: 35px;
}

section {
  margin: auto;
  width: 95%;
  height: 100%;
  color: black;
  background-color: white;
}

.categories {
  position: relative;
  top: 3px;
  color: white;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-weight: 300;
  word-spacing: 26px;
  padding-bottom: 2px;
}

.categories a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: inherit;
}

.legal {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 30px;
  font-weight: 300;
  word-spacing: 15px;
}

.legal a {
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 14px;
  color: white;
}

.quote {
  position: relative;
  margin: auto;
  font-size: 20px;
  font-weight: 300;
  bottom: 80px;
  height: 0;
}

.searchcontainer {
  position: relative;
  height: 0;
  bottom: 43px;
  margin: auto;
  width: 380px;
  ;
}

input[type=text] {
  width: 100%;
  display: inline-block;
  border: 2px solid #ddd;
  border-radius: 4px;
  padding: 6px 0 7px 40px;
  background-image: url('https://image.ibb.co/j9esac/searchicon.png');
  background-position: 10px 6px;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  font-size: 16px;
  background-color: white;
}

.innercircle {
  height: 89px;
  width: 89px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-color: white;
  margin: auto;
  position: relative;
  bottom: 93px;
}

.outercircle {
  height: 120px;
  width: 120px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-color: #007580;
  margin: auto;
  position: relative;
  top: 11px;
}

.D {
  font-size: 100px;
  font-weight: 100;
  position: relative;
  bottom: 196px;
  right: 3px;
  margin: auto;
  color: #007580;
  height: 0;
  font-family: 'Amiri', serif;
  letter-spacing: -10px;
}

.D a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: inherit;
}

.R {
  font-size: 55px;
  font-weight: 100;
  position: relative;
  bottom: 173px;
  right: 2px;
  margin: auto;
  color: #007580;
  height: 0;
  font-family: 'Amiri', serif;
  letter-spacing: -10px;
}

.R a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: inherit;
}

.ICONwhatsnew {
  position: relative;
  margin: auto;
  bottom: 194px;
  right: 191px;
  width: 0;
  display: block;
  height: 0;
}

.ICONwhatsnew a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: inherit;
}

.ICONworldlanguages {
  position: relative;
  margin: auto;
  bottom: 190px;
  right: 116px;
  width: 0;
  display: block;
  height: 0;
}

.ICONworldlanguages a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: inherit;
}

.ICONsignin {
  position: relative;
  margin: auto;
  bottom: 192px;
  left: 83px;
  width: 0;
  display: block;
  height: 0;
}

.ICONsignin a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: inherit;
}

.ICONcart {
  position: relative;
  margin: auto;
  bottom: 192px;
  left: 149px;
  width: 0;
  display: block;
  height: 0;
}

.ICONcart a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: inherit;
}

.container {
  font-size: 17px;
  font-weight: 400;
  color: #007580;
  top: 50%;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  position: absolute;
}

input[type=unams] {
  width: 80%;
  padding: 12px 45px;
  margin: 22px 0 0 0;
  border: 1px solid #007580;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border-radius: 0px;
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  font-size: 17px;
  background-image: url('https://image.ibb.co/fZHHnc/signin.png');
  background-position: 10px 8px;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: 25px;
}

input[type=password] {
  width: 80%;
  padding: 12px 45px;
  /* first is how big you want the input box 2nd is positioning of word password */
  margin: 22px 0 15px 0;
  border: 1px solid #007580;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border-radius: 0px;
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  font-size: 17px;
  background-image: url('https://image.ibb.co/jC7gfx/lock.png');
  background-position: 10px 8px;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: 25px;
}

.buttonlg {
  background-color: #007580;
  border: none;
  color: white;
  width: 25%;
  font-size: 17px;
  height: 38px;
  margin: auto;
  text-align: center;
}

.outerform {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.innerform {
  width: 90%;
  height: 90%;
}

.box {
  background-color: white;
  border: 1px solid #007580;
  height: 100%;
}

.animate {
  -webkit-animation: animatezoom 0.6s;
  animation: animatezoom 0.6s
}

@-webkit-keyframes animatezoom {
  from {
    -webkit-transform: scale(0)
  }
  to {
    -webkit-transform: scale(1)
  }
}

 ::-webkit-input-placeholder {
  /* WebKit browsers */
  color: lightgrey;
  opacity: 1 !important;
}

.circlelogo1 {
  background: #007580;
  border-radius: 50%;
  height: 30px;
  width: 30px;
  position: relative;
  margin: auto;
  /* 
    Child elements with absolute positioning will be 
     positioned relative to this div 
       */
}

.circlelogo2 {
  position: absolute;
  background: white;
  border-radius: 50%;
  height: 18px;
  width: 18px;
  /*
         Put top edge and left edge in the center
       */
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  margin: -9px 0px 0px -9px;
  /* 
        Offset the position correctly with
        minus half of the width and minus half of the height 
       */
}
```

```html
<div class="outercircle"></div>
<div class="innercircle"></div>
<div class="D">
  <a href="index.html">D</a>
</div>
<div class="R">
  <a href="index.html">R</a>
</div>
<div class="quote">
  You will always be your greatest investment.
</div>
<div class="searchcontainer">
  <form>
    <input name="search" placeholder="Search all resources..." type="text">
  </form>
</div>
<div class="ICONsignin">
  <a href="signin.html"><img height="37px" src="https://svgshare.com/i/5SR.svg"></a>
</div>
<div class="ICONcart">
  <a href="#"><img height="39px" src="https://svgshare.com/i/5SE.svg"></a>
</div>
<div class="ICONworldlanguages">
  <a href="#"><img height="34px" src="https://svgshare.com/i/5XW.svg"></a>
</div>
<div class="ICONwhatsnew">
  <a href="#"><img height="43px" src="https://svgshare.com/i/5aX.svg"></a>
</div>
<header>
  <div class="categories">
    <a href="#"><b>Categories</b></a> <a href="#home">Newest</a> <a href="#about">Popular</a> <a href="#about">Music</a> <a href="#about">Youth</a>
  </div>
</header>
<main>
  <section>
    <div class="outerform">
      <div class="innerform">
        <form class="animate box">
          <div class="container">
            <div class="circlelogo1">
              <div class="circlelogo2">
              </div>
            </div>
            <input type="unams" placeholder="Username" name="uname" required>
            <input type="password" placeholder="Password" name="psw" required><br>
            <button class="buttonlg" type="submit">Log In</button>
          </div>
        </form>
      </div>
    </div>
  </section>
</main>
<footer>
  <div class="legal">
    <a href="#home">Contact</a> <a href="#home">Privacy</a> <a href="#about">Terms</a> <a href="#about">Copyright</a> <a href="#home">About</a>
  </div>
</footer>
```

Comment: can you reduce the code to show us only the needed part ?

Comment: Yes sorry I am new here. Let me try to edit it now

Comment: I reduced the code does that help?

Comment: Centre it with flexbox. Remove the `position: absolute;` and centre it using `display: flex; align-items: center; justify-content: center;` on the `.box`: [See this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ato89dus/3/) - is that what you're after?

Comment: Yep thanks so much. I couldn’t figure out where to add the flex  option and got even more confused with the position element

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using `position:absolute` and the parent element is not set with relative so the form **is not relative to the scaled container** which is creating this issue. You need to set `position:relative` to the parent container and then adjust the centering:

```
.box {
  ...
  position:relative; /*Added this*/
}

.container {
  ...
  transform:translate(0,-50%); /*Added this*/
  top: 50%;
  ...
}
```

Here is the full code:

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  font-family: 'Lato', serif;
  background: linear-gradient(white 70px, #007580 70px);
  -webkit-text-size-adjust: none;
}

header,
footer {
  background: #007580
}

body,
main {
  display: flex;
  flex: 1;
}

body {
  flex-flow: column;
}

header {
  min-height: 35px;
}

footer {
  min-height: 35px;
}

section {
  margin: auto;
  width: 95%;
  height: 100%;
  color: black;
  background-color: white;
}

.categories {
  position: relative;
  top: 3px;
  color: white;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-weight: 300;
  word-spacing: 26px;
  padding-bottom: 2px;
}

.categories a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: inherit;
}

.legal {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 30px;
  font-weight: 300;
  word-spacing: 15px;
}

.legal a {
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 14px;
  color: white;
}

.quote {
  position: relative;
  margin: auto;
  font-size: 20px;
  font-weight: 300;
  bottom: 80px;
  height: 0;
}

.searchcontainer {
  position: relative;
  height: 0;
  bottom: 43px;
  margin: auto;
  width: 380px;
  ;
}

input[type=text] {
  width: 100%;
  display: inline-block;
  border: 2px solid #ddd;
  border-radius: 4px;
  padding: 6px 0 7px 40px;
  background-image: url('https://image.ibb.co/j9esac/searchicon.png');
  background-position: 10px 6px;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  font-size: 16px;
  background-color: white;
}

.innercircle {
  height: 89px;
  width: 89px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-color: white;
  margin: auto;
  position: relative;
  bottom: 93px;
}

.outercircle {
  height: 120px;
  width: 120px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-color: #007580;
  margin: auto;
  position: relative;
  top: 11px;
}

.D {
  font-size: 100px;
  font-weight: 100;
  position: relative;
  bottom: 196px;
  right: 3px;
  margin: auto;
  color: #007580;
  height: 0;
  font-family: 'Amiri', serif;
  letter-spacing: -10px;
}

.D a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: inherit;
}

.R {
  font-size: 55px;
  font-weight: 100;
  position: relative;
  bottom: 173px;
  right: 2px;
  margin: auto;
  color: #007580;
  height: 0;
  font-family: 'Amiri', serif;
  letter-spacing: -10px;
}

.R a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: inherit;
}

.ICONwhatsnew {
  position: relative;
  margin: auto;
  bottom: 194px;
  right: 191px;
  width: 0;
  display: block;
  height: 0;
}

.ICONwhatsnew a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: inherit;
}

.ICONworldlanguages {
  position: relative;
  margin: auto;
  bottom: 190px;
  right: 116px;
  width: 0;
  display: block;
  height: 0;
}

.ICONworldlanguages a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: inherit;
}

.ICONsignin {
  position: relative;
  margin: auto;
  bottom: 192px;
  left: 83px;
  width: 0;
  display: block;
  height: 0;
}

.ICONsignin a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: inherit;
}

.ICONcart {
  position: relative;
  margin: auto;
  bottom: 192px;
  left: 149px;
  width: 0;
  display: block;
  height: 0;
}

.ICONcart a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: inherit;
}

.container {
  font-size: 17px;
  font-weight: 400;
  color: #007580;
  transform:translate(0,-50%);
  top: 50%;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  position: absolute;
}

input[type=unams] {
  width: 80%;
  padding: 12px 45px;
  margin: 22px 0 0 0;
  border: 1px solid #007580;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border-radius: 0px;
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  font-size: 17px;
  background-image: url('https://image.ibb.co/fZHHnc/signin.png');
  background-position: 10px 8px;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: 25px;
}

input[type=password] {
  width: 80%;
  padding: 12px 45px;
  /* first is how big you want the input box 2nd is positioning of word password */
  margin: 22px 0 15px 0;
  border: 1px solid #007580;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border-radius: 0px;
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  font-size: 17px;
  background-image: url('https://image.ibb.co/jC7gfx/lock.png');
  background-position: 10px 8px;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: 25px;
}

.buttonlg {
  background-color: #007580;
  border: none;
  color: white;
  width: 25%;
  font-size: 17px;
  height: 38px;
  margin: auto;
  text-align: center;
}

.outerform {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.innerform {
  width: 90%;
  height: 90%;
}

.box {
  background-color: white;
  border: 1px solid #007580;
  height: 100%;
  position:relative;
}

.animate {
  -webkit-animation: animatezoom 0.6s;
  animation: animatezoom 0.6s
}

@-webkit-keyframes animatezoom {
  from {
    -webkit-transform: scale(0)
  }
  to {
    -webkit-transform: scale(1)
  }
}

 ::-webkit-input-placeholder {
  /* WebKit browsers */
  color: lightgrey;
  opacity: 1 !important;
}

.circlelogo1 {
  background: #007580;
  border-radius: 50%;
  height: 30px;
  width: 30px;
  position: relative;
  margin: auto;
  /* 
    Child elements with absolute positioning will be 
     positioned relative to this div 
       */
}

.circlelogo2 {
  position: absolute;
  background: white;
  border-radius: 50%;
  height: 18px;
  width: 18px;
  /*
         Put top edge and left edge in the center
       */
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  margin: -9px 0px 0px -9px;
  /* 
        Offset the position correctly with
        minus half of the width and minus half of the height 
       */
}
```

```html
<div class="outercircle"></div>
<div class="innercircle"></div>
<div class="D">
  <a href="index.html">D</a>
</div>
<div class="R">
  <a href="index.html">R</a>
</div>
<div class="quote">
  You will always be your greatest investment.
</div>
<div class="searchcontainer">
  <form>
    <input name="search" placeholder="Search all resources..." type="text">
  </form>
</div>
<div class="ICONsignin">
  <a href="signin.html"><img height="37px" src="https://svgshare.com/i/5SR.svg"></a>
</div>
<div class="ICONcart">
  <a href="#"><img height="39px" src="https://svgshare.com/i/5SE.svg"></a>
</div>
<div class="ICONworldlanguages">
  <a href="#"><img height="34px" src="https://svgshare.com/i/5XW.svg"></a>
</div>
<div class="ICONwhatsnew">
  <a href="#"><img height="43px" src="https://svgshare.com/i/5aX.svg"></a>
</div>
<header>
  <div class="categories">
    <a href="#"><b>Categories</b></a> <a href="#home">Newest</a> <a href="#about">Popular</a> <a href="#about">Music</a> <a href="#about">Youth</a>
  </div>
</header>
<main>
  <section>
    <div class="outerform">
      <div class="innerform">
        <form class="animate box">
          <div class="container">
            <div class="circlelogo1">
              <div class="circlelogo2">
              </div>
            </div>
            <input type="unams" placeholder="Username" name="uname" required>
            <input type="password" placeholder="Password" name="psw" required><br>
            <button class="buttonlg" type="submit">Log In</button>
          </div>
        </form>
      </div>
    </div>
  </section>
</main>
<footer>
  <div class="legal">
    <a href="#home">Contact</a> <a href="#home">Privacy</a> <a href="#about">Terms</a> <a href="#about">Copyright</a> <a href="#home">About</a>
  </div>
</footer>
```

---

By the way it's better to consider another way than positioned element to center. You can do it with flex since you are already using it:

```
.box {
  ....
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}
```

Then remove everything related to positionning from `.container`.

Here is the full code:

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  font-family: 'Lato', serif;
  background: linear-gradient(white 70px, #007580 70px);
  -webkit-text-size-adjust: none;
}

header,
footer {
  background: #007580
}

body,
main {
  display: flex;
  flex: 1;
}

body {
  flex-flow: column;
}

header {
  min-height: 35px;
}

footer {
  min-height: 35px;
}

section {
  margin: auto;
  width: 95%;
  height: 100%;
  color: black;
  background-color: white;
}

.categories {
  position: relative;
  top: 3px;
  color: white;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-weight: 300;
  word-spacing: 26px;
  padding-bottom: 2px;
}

.categories a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: inherit;
}

.legal {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 30px;
  font-weight: 300;
  word-spacing: 15px;
}

.legal a {
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 14px;
  color: white;
}

.quote {
  position: relative;
  margin: auto;
  font-size: 20px;
  font-weight: 300;
  bottom: 80px;
  height: 0;
}

.searchcontainer {
  position: relative;
  height: 0;
  bottom: 43px;
  margin: auto;
  width: 380px;
  ;
}

input[type=text] {
  width: 100%;
  display: inline-block;
  border: 2px solid #ddd;
  border-radius: 4px;
  padding: 6px 0 7px 40px;
  background-image: url('https://image.ibb.co/j9esac/searchicon.png');
  background-position: 10px 6px;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  font-size: 16px;
  background-color: white;
}

.innercircle {
  height: 89px;
  width: 89px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-color: white;
  margin: auto;
  position: relative;
  bottom: 93px;
}

.outercircle {
  height: 120px;
  width: 120px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-color: #007580;
  margin: auto;
  position: relative;
  top: 11px;
}

.D {
  font-size: 100px;
  font-weight: 100;
  position: relative;
  bottom: 196px;
  right: 3px;
  margin: auto;
  color: #007580;
  height: 0;
  font-family: 'Amiri', serif;
  letter-spacing: -10px;
}

.D a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: inherit;
}

.R {
  font-size: 55px;
  font-weight: 100;
  position: relative;
  bottom: 173px;
  right: 2px;
  margin: auto;
  color: #007580;
  height: 0;
  font-family: 'Amiri', serif;
  letter-spacing: -10px;
}

.R a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: inherit;
}

.ICONwhatsnew {
  position: relative;
  margin: auto;
  bottom: 194px;
  right: 191px;
  width: 0;
  display: block;
  height: 0;
}

.ICONwhatsnew a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: inherit;
}

.ICONworldlanguages {
  position: relative;
  margin: auto;
  bottom: 190px;
  right: 116px;
  width: 0;
  display: block;
  height: 0;
}

.ICONworldlanguages a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: inherit;
}

.ICONsignin {
  position: relative;
  margin: auto;
  bottom: 192px;
  left: 83px;
  width: 0;
  display: block;
  height: 0;
}

.ICONsignin a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: inherit;
}

.ICONcart {
  position: relative;
  margin: auto;
  bottom: 192px;
  left: 149px;
  width: 0;
  display: block;
  height: 0;
}

.ICONcart a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: inherit;
}

.container {
  font-size: 17px;
  font-weight: 400;
  color: #007580;
}

input[type=unams] {
  width: 80%;
  padding: 12px 45px;
  margin: 22px 0 0 0;
  border: 1px solid #007580;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border-radius: 0px;
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  font-size: 17px;
  background-image: url('https://image.ibb.co/fZHHnc/signin.png');
  background-position: 10px 8px;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: 25px;
}

input[type=password] {
  width: 80%;
  padding: 12px 45px;
  /* first is how big you want the input box 2nd is positioning of word password */
  margin: 22px 0 15px 0;
  border: 1px solid #007580;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border-radius: 0px;
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  font-size: 17px;
  background-image: url('https://image.ibb.co/jC7gfx/lock.png');
  background-position: 10px 8px;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: 25px;
}

.buttonlg {
  background-color: #007580;
  border: none;
  color: white;
  width: 25%;
  font-size: 17px;
  height: 38px;
  margin: auto;
  text-align: center;
}

.outerform {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.innerform {
  width: 90%;
  height: 90%;
}

.box {
  background-color: white;
  border: 1px solid #007580;
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.animate {
  -webkit-animation: animatezoom 0.6s;
  animation: animatezoom 0.6s
}

@-webkit-keyframes animatezoom {
  from {
    -webkit-transform: scale(0)
  }
  to {
    -webkit-transform: scale(1)
  }
}

 ::-webkit-input-placeholder {
  /* WebKit browsers */
  color: lightgrey;
  opacity: 1 !important;
}

.circlelogo1 {
  background: #007580;
  border-radius: 50%;
  height: 30px;
  width: 30px;
  position: relative;
  margin: auto;
  /* 
    Child elements with absolute positioning will be 
     positioned relative to this div 
       */
}

.circlelogo2 {
  position: absolute;
  background: white;
  border-radius: 50%;
  height: 18px;
  width: 18px;
  /*
         Put top edge and left edge in the center
       */
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  margin: -9px 0px 0px -9px;
  /* 
        Offset the position correctly with
        minus half of the width and minus half of the height 
       */
}
```

```html
<div class="outercircle"></div>
<div class="innercircle"></div>
<div class="D">
  <a href="index.html">D</a>
</div>
<div class="R">
  <a href="index.html">R</a>
</div>
<div class="quote">
  You will always be your greatest investment.
</div>
<div class="searchcontainer">
  <form>
    <input name="search" placeholder="Search all resources..." type="text">
  </form>
</div>
<div class="ICONsignin">
  <a href="signin.html"><img height="37px" src="https://svgshare.com/i/5SR.svg"></a>
</div>
<div class="ICONcart">
  <a href="#"><img height="39px" src="https://svgshare.com/i/5SE.svg"></a>
</div>
<div class="ICONworldlanguages">
  <a href="#"><img height="34px" src="https://svgshare.com/i/5XW.svg"></a>
</div>
<div class="ICONwhatsnew">
  <a href="#"><img height="43px" src="https://svgshare.com/i/5aX.svg"></a>
</div>
<header>
  <div class="categories">
    <a href="#"><b>Categories</b></a> <a href="#home">Newest</a> <a href="#about">Popular</a> <a href="#about">Music</a> <a href="#about">Youth</a>
  </div>
</header>
<main>
  <section>
    <div class="outerform">
      <div class="innerform">
        <form class="animate box">
          <div class="container">
            <div class="circlelogo1">
              <div class="circlelogo2">
              </div>
            </div>
            <input type="unams" placeholder="Username" name="uname" required>
            <input type="password" placeholder="Password" name="psw" required><br>
            <button class="buttonlg" type="submit">Log In</button>
          </div>
        </form>
      </div>
    </div>
  </section>
</main>
<footer>
  <div class="legal">
    <a href="#home">Contact</a> <a href="#home">Privacy</a> <a href="#about">Terms</a> <a href="#about">Copyright</a> <a href="#home">About</a>
  </div>
</footer>
```

Comment: Perfect! Thank you so much. Now I'm starting to understand parent elements more clearly with positioned elements. Can you show me notes /* with what you added and/or changed for the flex option you recommended? Like you did with the position showing me what you added

Comment: I noticed the top and bottom lines for both form input boxes for username and password became blurry in chrome after I added the code you suggessted. Do you know why?

Comment: actually the flex box suggestion fixes the blurry issue, but the flex box option makes the width of my form in IE stretched out all the way across. Help?

Comment: @SCodeSK71 you mean what bu blurry ? it's fine for me on chrome ... for IE its because the support of flex is limited https://caniuse.com/#search=flexbox you need to use some prefixes or search for workarounds

Answer (score 0):

There's a few issues. In your `.box` styling you should add `position: relative;` this will force `.container`'s absolute positioning to respect its parent, in this case `.box`'s positioning and size. The second is the `top: 50%;` on `.container`. In certain scenarios that can seem to center the item but in others it does not. What you can do to center `.container` within `.box` is add `transform: translate(0, -50%);` which offsets `top: 50%` and centers the element. Same can be done horizontally with `left: 50%` and `transform: translate(-50%, -50%);`.

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  font-family: 'Lato', serif;
  background: linear-gradient(white 70px, #007580 70px);
  -webkit-text-size-adjust: none;
}

header,
footer {
  background: #007580
}

body,
main {
  display: flex;
  flex: 1;
}

body {
  flex-flow: column;
}

header {
  min-height: 35px;
}

footer {
  min-height: 35px;
}

section {
  margin: auto;
  width: 95%;
  height: 100%;
  color: black;
  background-color: white;
}

.categories {
  position: relative;
  top: 3px;
  color: white;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-weight: 300;
  word-spacing: 26px;
  padding-bottom: 2px;
}

.categories a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: inherit;
}

.legal {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 30px;
  font-weight: 300;
  word-spacing: 15px;
}

.legal a {
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 14px;
  color: white;
}

.quote {
  position: relative;
  margin: auto;
  font-size: 20px;
  font-weight: 300;
  bottom: 80px;
  height: 0;
}

.searchcontainer {
  position: relative;
  height: 0;
  bottom: 43px;
  margin: auto;
  width: 380px;
  ;
}

input[type=text] {
  width: 100%;
  display: inline-block;
  border: 2px solid #ddd;
  border-radius: 4px;
  padding: 6px 0 7px 40px;
  background-image: url('https://image.ibb.co/j9esac/searchicon.png');
  background-position: 10px 6px;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  font-size: 16px;
  background-color: white;
}

.innercircle {
  height: 89px;
  width: 89px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-color: white;
  margin: auto;
  position: relative;
  bottom: 93px;
}

.outercircle {
  height: 120px;
  width: 120px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-color: #007580;
  margin: auto;
  position: relative;
  top: 11px;
}

.D {
  font-size: 100px;
  font-weight: 100;
  position: relative;
  bottom: 196px;
  right: 3px;
  margin: auto;
  color: #007580;
  height: 0;
  font-family: 'Amiri', serif;
  letter-spacing: -10px;
}

.D a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: inherit;
}

.R {
  font-size: 55px;
  font-weight: 100;
  position: relative;
  bottom: 173px;
  right: 2px;
  margin: auto;
  color: #007580;
  height: 0;
  font-family: 'Amiri', serif;
  letter-spacing: -10px;
}

.R a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: inherit;
}

.ICONwhatsnew {
  position: relative;
  margin: auto;
  bottom: 194px;
  right: 191px;
  width: 0;
  display: block;
  height: 0;
}

.ICONwhatsnew a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: inherit;
}

.ICONworldlanguages {
  position: relative;
  margin: auto;
  bottom: 190px;
  right: 116px;
  width: 0;
  display: block;
  height: 0;
}

.ICONworldlanguages a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: inherit;
}

.ICONsignin {
  position: relative;
  margin: auto;
  bottom: 192px;
  left: 83px;
  width: 0;
  display: block;
  height: 0;
}

.ICONsignin a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: inherit;
}

.ICONcart {
  position: relative;
  margin: auto;
  bottom: 192px;
  left: 149px;
  width: 0;
  display: block;
  height: 0;
}

.ICONcart a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: inherit;
}

.container {
  font-size: 17px;
  font-weight: 400;
  color: #007580;
  top: 50%;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  position: absolute;
  transform: translate(0, -50%);
}

input[type=unams] {
  width: 80%;
  padding: 12px 45px;
  margin: 22px 0 0 0;
  border: 1px solid #007580;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border-radius: 0px;
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  font-size: 17px;
  background-image: url('https://image.ibb.co/fZHHnc/signin.png');
  background-position: 10px 8px;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: 25px;
}

input[type=password] {
  width: 80%;
  padding: 12px 45px;
  /* first is how big you want the input box 2nd is positioning of word password */
  margin: 22px 0 15px 0;
  border: 1px solid #007580;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border-radius: 0px;
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  font-size: 17px;
  background-image: url('https://image.ibb.co/jC7gfx/lock.png');
  background-position: 10px 8px;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: 25px;
}

.buttonlg {
  background-color: #007580;
  border: none;
  color: white;
  width: 25%;
  font-size: 17px;
  height: 38px;
  margin: auto;
  text-align: center;
}

.outerform {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.innerform {
  width: 90%;
  height: 90%;
}

.box {
position: relative;
  background-color: white;
  border: 1px solid #007580;
  height: 100%;
}

.animate {
  -webkit-animation: animatezoom 0.6s;
  animation: animatezoom 0.6s
}

@-webkit-keyframes animatezoom {
  from {
    -webkit-transform: scale(0)
  }
  to {
    -webkit-transform: scale(1)
  }
}

 ::-webkit-input-placeholder {
  /* WebKit browsers */
  color: lightgrey;
  opacity: 1 !important;
}

.circlelogo1 {
  background: #007580;
  border-radius: 50%;
  height: 30px;
  width: 30px;
  position: relative;
  margin: auto;
  /* 
    Child elements with absolute positioning will be 
     positioned relative to this div 
       */
}

.circlelogo2 {
  position: absolute;
  background: white;
  border-radius: 50%;
  height: 18px;
  width: 18px;
  /*
         Put top edge and left edge in the center
       */
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  margin: -9px 0px 0px -9px;
  /* 
        Offset the position correctly with
        minus half of the width and minus half of the height 
       */
}
```

```html
<div class="outercircle"></div>
<div class="innercircle"></div>
<div class="D">
  <a href="index.html">D</a>
</div>
<div class="R">
  <a href="index.html">R</a>
</div>
<div class="quote">
  You will always be your greatest investment.
</div>
<div class="searchcontainer">
  <form>
    <input name="search" placeholder="Search all resources..." type="text">
  </form>
</div>
<div class="ICONsignin">
  <a href="signin.html"><img height="37px" src="https://svgshare.com/i/5SR.svg"></a>
</div>
<div class="ICONcart">
  <a href="#"><img height="39px" src="https://svgshare.com/i/5SE.svg"></a>
</div>
<div class="ICONworldlanguages">
  <a href="#"><img height="34px" src="https://svgshare.com/i/5XW.svg"></a>
</div>
<div class="ICONwhatsnew">
  <a href="#"><img height="43px" src="https://svgshare.com/i/5aX.svg"></a>
</div>
<header>
  <div class="categories">
    <a href="#"><b>Categories</b></a> <a href="#home">Newest</a> <a href="#about">Popular</a> <a href="#about">Music</a> <a href="#about">Youth</a>
  </div>
</header>
<main>
  <section>
    <div class="outerform">
      <div class="innerform">
        <form class="animate box">
          <div class="container">
            <div class="circlelogo1">
              <div class="circlelogo2">
              </div>
            </div>
            <input type="unams" placeholder="Username" name="uname" required>
            <input type="password" placeholder="Password" name="psw" required><br>
            <button class="buttonlg" type="submit">Log In</button>
          </div>
        </form>
      </div>
    </div>
  </section>
</main>
<footer>
  <div class="legal">
    <a href="#home">Contact</a> <a href="#home">Privacy</a> <a href="#about">Terms</a> <a href="#about">Copyright</a> <a href="#home">About</a>
  </div>
</footer>
```